# How to get the file length for an file in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I am using file upload in that i have added a validation if there is no file then display an error message. I am able to get the file length but when the page gets refreshed i am getting the image as well. I don't know how to get the file length from it.can anyone help me to sort this issue Thanks in advance.

[image]

Conditions i have used:

```
    if (!values.profilePicture) {
    errors.profilePicture = 'Employee Image Required';
  } else if (values.profilePicture && values.profilePicture.length === 0) {
    console.log('values.profilePicture.length', Object.keys(values.profilePicture).length);
    errors.profilePicture = 'Employee Image Required';
  }
```

Comment: `values.profilePicture.length` doesn't work?

Comment: @Smarticles101 It works initially but when i refresh it is not working

Comment: You could try checking if `values.profilePicture[0]` exists?

Answer (score 9):

Every file which you want to upload has file size property you can get that property `onChange` event.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="profilePic" onChange={(e)=>this.uploadImage(e)}>
```

and `uploadImage` function should be like

```
uploadImage=(e)=>{
  let file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file && !file.name) {
       window.alert("Please select a file");
       return false;
    }
    if (file.size > 10e6) {
      window.alert("Please upload a file smaller than 10 MB");
      return false;
    }
}
```

Note: 10e6 is 10mb file size.